# Are localized rings always flat as $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

We know this is true for commutative ring, but if $S\subset R$ is a left and right Ore set, and $S^{-1}R$ its localization by this Ore set, is this always a flat $R$-module?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Proposition 2.1.16 in McConnel+Robson's book on *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings*.

Comment: The proof was easy, thanks for the tip, here is the link for others who may be looking and don't own the book: http://books.google.com/books?id=c3fWk8LoSvgC&lpg=PP1&dq=McConnell%20Robson&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in a prior [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/learning-to-think-categorically-localization-of-rings-and-modules/4450#4450) there is a wealth of information on noncommutative localizations in Ranicki, A.(ed). [Noncommutative localization in algebra and topology. ICMS 2002](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/nlat.pdf). In particular, there you will find an interesting paper on this very topic by Beachy: "On flatness and the Ore condition". Below is general reference information for flatness in the commutative case.

There is a very nice treatment of flatness in Bourbaki's "Commutative Algebra" - which begins with an excellent chapter on flat modules before turning to localizations in Chapter 2 (see Theorem 2.41. p. 68 for the result you seek). Also perhaps of interest is the following motivational remark from the introduction

> The study of the passage from a ring $\rm A$ to a local ring $\rm A$, or to a completion 
>   $\rm \hat A$ brings to light a feature common to these two operations, the property of 
>   flatness of the $\rm A$-modules $\rm A$, and $\rm \hat A$, which allows amongst other things 
>   the use of tensor products of such $\rm A$-modules with arbitrary $\rm A$-modules somewhat 
>   similar to that of tensor products of vector spaces, that is, without all the precautions 
>   surrounding their use in the general case. The properties associated with this notion, which 
>   are also applicable to modules over non-commutative rings, are  the object of study in Chapter I.

See also Atiyah and Macdonald, Corollary 3.6 and Proposition 3.10 pp. 40-41.

Comment: Note that Bryan is asking specifically about localization in the noncommutative setting.

Comment: @97832123: Yes, I realized that later. Somehow I missed it at first glance - perhaps due to the absence of "noncommutative" in the title combined with too small a phone LCD. Since a couple readers found the answer useful I decided against deleting it.

Comment: I agree that you should not delete it. Mostly because somebody trying to understand the commutative version might stumble across this and find it useful. I hope that you understand if I don't vote it up though.

Comment: @BBischof: My answer is now updated for the noncommutative case.