# Is every commutative ring contained in a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I imagine the answer to this question is very simple, but I haven't been able to locate it.

Can every commutative ring be imbedded in a field? This seems very plausible to me, for it seems we could just take the "closure" under inverses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> A commutative ring can be embedded in a field iff it is an integral domain.

Indeed, if a ring can be embedded in a field then it cannot have zero divisors because fields cannot have zero divisors.

Conversely, every integral domain can be embedded in a field, namely, its field of fractions.

Comment: Does this generalize to the non-commutative case? I mean, is it true that a ring can be embedded in a __skew field__ if and only if that ring has no zero divisors (neither left zero divisors nor right zero divisors)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, perhaps ask a separate question. But first see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336893/can-we-embed-cancellative-rings-into-division-rings.

Comment: That is a nice reference, and it seems there is no need for me to repeat their Math SE question. Reading the two answers currently there, I see (1) that [Maltsev (Malcev, Mal'cev, Ма́льцев)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Maltsev) already proved the answer is "no", (2) that the [Ore condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition) (after [Ø. Ore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98ystein_Ore)) is what extra hypothesis we need to make this work. The Wikipedia Ore condition article I link, under section _Application_, also gives a clear answer to the question I raised.

Answer (score 14):

No. Every nonzero element of a field is invertible; commutative rings can contain zero divisors.

The "closure" operation you're talking about is localization. In a (commutative) domain $A$, localizing at $0$ gives you the field of fractions $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$ of $A$, and the canonical map $A \to \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is an embedding. In general, the localization is a more complicated ring than just a field.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Define $\bar Q(R)=R\times (R-\{0\})$ as the set of pairs $(r,s)$ with $r,s\in R$ and $s\not=0$. We define the equivalence relation
$$(r,s)\sim(r',s')\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad rs'=sr'.$$
We define $Q(R):=\bar Q(R)/\!\!\sim$ and give it a ring structure (denoting by $x$ the equivalence class that contains $x$) via

$$(r,s)+(r',s')=(rs'+sr',ss'),\qquad (r,s)\cdot (r',s')=(rr',ss').$$

This turns out to be well-defined if and only if $R$ was an integral domain. Then $Q(R)$ will be a field $-$ the *field of fractions*. Think of $(r,s)\in Q(R)$ as the fraction $r/s$ or the element $rs^{-1}$. $R$ can be embedded into $Q(R)$ via  $r\mapsto(rx,x)$ for arbitrary $x$. The zero and unity of $Q(R)$ are $(0,x)$ and $(x,x)$ respectively. A non-zero element $(r,s)$ has the inverse $(s,r)$.

Comment: Something seems to be not okay with my answer (therefore the downvote?). I can improve or remove it if it will be explained what is the problem.

Comment: There's a downvote for each of these answers, though they all seem perfectly fine to me. Maybe just a wandering troll.

Comment: Compensating the downvote..