# isomorphism for multiplicative systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

> Let $A$ be a unit commutative ring and $S:= \{a^n | a \in A, n\geq 0\}$. With $S^{-1}A$ the localization of $A$ over $S$.

I'm having some problems on proving that
$$S^{-1}A \cong A[X]/(1-ax)$$
I'm not searching for a complete solution maybe just some hints, thank you very much.

Comment: Where should $x$ map to in the isomorphism $A[x]/(1-ax)\to S^{-1}A$? There is a very clear and canonical choice.

Comment: @daruma Now I understand. If I define the morphism from $A[x]$ to $S^{-1}A$ and "luckily" the Kernel of the morphism is $(1-ax)$ do you think it's a "cleaner" solution or is just a waste of time? Thank you

Comment: I think you get the idea. I hope it is clear that $x\mapsto 1/a$ this way.

Comment: yea, clear as day. I was thinking to the Kernel so this way you shouldn't be annoyed by verifying things are well defined etc @daruma

Comment: Please use the search feature. This question has been asked many, many times before: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2188891), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/655738), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152236), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765382), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/839555)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
Let $b\in A$, then note that $bx^{i}=b(a^{k}x^{i+k})$. This would let you to the map that you want