# Why rings of fraction is defined as that?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be the commutative ring, S be the multiplicative set. As we know in $S^{-1}R$,  $a/b\sim c/d$ iff there is a $t \in S$ such that $adt=bct$. The question is that why we need $t$? Why not just defining $a/b\sim c/d$ iff $ad=bc$? Thank you!

Comment: Note how it plays a key role in the proof that $\,\sim\,$ is transitive. $\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an integral domain, then the $t$ doesn't matter because $adt=bct$ iff $(ad-bc)t=0$, and if $t\not=0$, $ad-bc=0$.  The problem comes up when rings have zero divisors.

Suppose $a\in S$ and $a$ is a zero divisor with $ab=0$.  Let $d\in S$ such that $bd\not=0$.  In this case, $b/c=0/a$ since $ab=0c$.  Also, $0/a=0/d$ since $0d=0a$.  The problem is that without multiplying by $t$, you would have a problem with $b/c=0/d$ since $bd\not=0c$, but, by multiplying both sides by $a$ you get $abd=0ac$, which is true.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,sr=0\,$ in $\,R\,$ then in $\,S^{-1}R$ we have $\,r=0\,$ because $\,s\,$ is a unit so cancellable.  Hence, necessarily, all elements of that form will be killed in $\,S^{-1} R.\,$ This necessary condition turns out to be sufficient, as the proof you are reading shows.

**Remark** $\ $ A simpler and more natural way to construct localizations is to universally adjoin inverses of all $\rm\,s\in S\,$ to $\rm\,R.\,$ via $\rm\,S^{-1} R = R[x_i]/(s_i x_i - 1).\,$ This allows one to exploit the universal properties of quotient rings and polynomial rings to *quickly* construct and derive the basic properties of localizations. In particular, the calculation of the kernel is quite simple and natural from that viewpoint - see the two-line proof [I give here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162037/242)