# If $\det A=1$ and the matrices $A^{2015}$ and $A^{2017}$ are integer, is $A$ an integer matrix?

Tags: matrices

Assume $\det(A) = 1$ and all the numbers in the matrices $A^{2015}$ and $A^{2017}$ are integers.
Can I say that all numbers in $A$ are integers too?
How can I prove it?

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: This is a nice problem. I'm tempted to obfuscate it even further by replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with a ring like $\mathbb{Z}/2^{64}\mathbb{Z}$ ("matrices using computer integer arithmetic") and 1 with a different unit.

Comment: @user7530 Or, you could go the other way an abstract it to the point of simplicity: If a subgroup contains $g^n$ and $g^m$, then it contains $g^{(m,n)}$.

Comment: I assume that by "integer matrix" you mean a matrix whose entries are all integers. Is this correct?

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** If $M$ is an integer matrix with $\det(M)=1$, them $M^{-1}$ is also an integer matrix.  Also, the product of two integer matrices is an integer matrix.

Comment: I didnt understand you.. may you explain please?thanks

Comment: Do you not understand what the hint says? Or why the hint is true?  Or how to use the hint?

Comment: how to use it ...

Comment: You can sort of proceed like the Euclidean algorithm.  $A^{2015}$ will have determinant $1$ and have integer entries, and hence, so will $A^{-2015}$, and hence so will $A^2=A^{-2015}A^{2017}$.  Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: nope :/ can you help me more please?

Comment: I'm afraid that if I say much more, it will keep you from thinking about the problem enough to actually understand what is going on.  But try using the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of 2015 and 2017, and then look back at what I've written.

Comment: the gcd of it is of course 1 ... but how can it help me?

Comment: It seems that $A^{2013}$ is also an integer matrix. @Rotemben

Comment: why?? I dont get you. ..

Comment: Because $A^{2013}=A^{-2}A^{2015}$.

Comment: @Rotemben And the goal is $A = A^1$.

Comment: but I get like that only A^2 again ...

Comment: Again, calculate the GCD(2015,2017) explicitly with the Euclidean algorithm (and NOT by factoring or some other method).  Look at the numbers that appear and the particular calculations that you do.  See if you can't find a way to transport what you do in that problem over to this problem.

Comment: cant find the connection :/

Comment: Can you show that $A^{2013}$ is integer matrix? If yes, how about $A^{2011}$? how about $A^{2009}$? how about...... @Rotemben

Comment: so ... i get A^-2 is integer (from A^-2017 * A^2015) and then got A^2013 from A^2015*A^-2 and so on?

Comment: Even simpler: $A^2$ is an integer matrix, so $A^{2016}=(A^2)^{1013}$ is also an integer matrix. No need for recursion, though it also works of course. Now check determinant, and apply the same trick as above to get $A^2$, and you'll find $A$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or follow the idea of jca  @Rotemben

Comment: @jca That is certainly faster, and likely something I would use in a proof I was writing for myself.  I don't know that it is conceptually simpler.  Sometimes calculations can uncover what is going on, but sometimes calculations can obscure the underlying idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, let $\,S\,$ be a group of $\,n\times n\,$ matrices, i.e. $S$ is closed under multiplication and inverses, e.g. matrices with all integer entries having determinant $= 1$ (inverse-closed by Cramer's rule).

**Theorem** $\ \  A^J, A^K\in S\,\Rightarrow\, A^{\gcd(J,K)}\!\in S$

**Proof** $\ $ By Bezout  $\ \gcd(J,K) = IJ+NK\,$ for some integers $\,I,N.$

Therefore $\ A^{\gcd(J,K)}\! = A^{IJ+NK}\! = (A^J)^I (A^K)^N \in S\ $ since $\,A^J,A^K\in S\,$ and $\,S\,$ is closed under multiplication so, by induction, under powers, including *negative* powers - by inverse closure (note that $\,I\,$ or $\,N\,$ may be negative in the Bezout equation).

**Remark** $\ $ Similarly we have  $\, A^J= B^J,\, A^K = B^K\,\Rightarrow\, A^D = B^D\,$ for $\,D = \gcd(J,K)\,$ when both $\,A,B\,$ are cancellable, e.g. see the [domain case here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1255979/242)

Comment: This was an answer to a recent question that was closed as a dupe of this question before I could post it, so I have migrated it here.