# If $q\mid 2^p + 3^p$ then $q \gt p$

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

> Let $p, q$ *positive prime numbers*, $q > 5$. Prove that if
>   $q \mid \left(2^{p} + 3^{p}\right)$ then $q > p$.

---

First, it's clear that $p \ne q$ because, using Fermat's little theorem, $2^p = 2 \mod p$ and $3^p = 3 \mod p$, therefore $5=0 \mod p$ false because $q \gt 5$.

Now suppose $q \lt p$. I tried to analyse $2^p +3^p \mod q$ but I didn't get a contradiction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of "order"? (as in Lab's proof)  If not, I can give a more elementary proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am familiar

Comment: Great, then using the order as in Lab's answer is probably the simplest way to proceed. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1255707/242) for a generalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

For $p>2$

$$\left(-\dfrac32\right)^p\equiv1\pmod q$$

$\implies$ord$_q(-3/2)|(p,q-1)$

But As $p$ is prime, ord$_q(-3/2)=1$ or $p$

ord$_q(-3/2)=1\implies-3\equiv2\pmod q\iff5\equiv0\iff q|5\implies q=5$

Else $p|(q-1)$

Comment: In fact, one can from here prove the stronger statement that $q > 2p$.