# Finding the kernel of $k[x,y] \rightarrow k[t,\frac{1}{t}], x \mapsto t+\frac{1}{t}, y\mapsto \frac{1}{t}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

> How does one find the kernel of the map $k[x,y] \rightarrow k[t,\frac{1}{t}], x \mapsto t+\frac{1}{t}, y\mapsto \frac{1}{t}$?

I know it's related with the old questions of finding the coordinate ring of hyperbola. But here the kernel contains $(y^2-xy+1)$. I tried by dividing an arbitrary element in the kernel by this and to show that the term $\frac{1}{t}A(t+\frac{1}{t})+B(t+\frac{1}{t})=0$ then $A=B=0$ but couldn't succeed. We can observe $m+1=\deg(B)+1+\deg(A)$ and wrote $A(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m+1}a_ix^i$ and $B(x) =\sum_{i=0}^{m}b_ix^i$. Plugging them in I got $a_0=b_0, a_1=b_1-b_0, \ldots, a_m=b_m-b_{m-1}, a_{m+1}=b_m$, implying $A(x), B(x)$ need not be zero. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more details on where your attempt failed? The strategy looks likely to succeed!

Comment: In showing $A=B=0$

Comment: Right, can you be more specific? What did you try at that stage of the problem?

Comment: well, even if $A$ or $B \neq 0$ we can have  $\frac{1}{t}A(t+\frac{1}{t})+B(t+\frac{1}{t})=0$. Which shoudnt happen.

Comment: Really? Do you have an example, because that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: we can observe $m+1=deg(B)+1+deg(A)$ and wrote $A(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m+1}a_ix^i$ and $B(x) =\sum_{i=0}^{m}b_ix^i$. Plugging them in  i got some relations among the coeffiecients and I'm confused.

Comment: If you edit more details of your attempt in to your post, I'd be more than happy to write an answer. You should include the relations you claim to have found, for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122918/discussion-between-varadharajan-r-and-kreiser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've successfully plugged in $x=t+1/t$ to get those relations between the coefficients - there should be a lot more going on there. For instance, if $A$ and $B$ are quadratic, we get $\frac1t(a_2t^2+2a_2+a_2t^{-2}+a_1t+a_1t^{-1}+a_0)+(b_2t^2+2b_2+b_2t^{-2}+b_1t+b_1t^{-1}+b_0)=0$, which doesn't give the relations you've written down.

Instead, I suggest that you look at the biggest (most positive) and smallest (most negative) powers of $t$ in the $\frac1t A(t+1/t)$ and $B(t+1/t)$ and consider what must happen to make $\frac1t A(t+1/t)+B(t+1/t)=0$. I've placed the details under the spoiler so you can make your own attempt before reading mine:

> If $B$ is of degree $b$, then the biggest and smallest powers of $t$ in $B(t+1/t)$ are $t^b$ and $t^{-b}$. If $A\neq 0$ is of degree $a$, then the biggest and smallest powers of $t$ in in $\frac1t A(t+1/t)$ are $t^{a-1}$ and $t^{-a-1}$. What has to happen in order for $\frac1t A(t+1/t) + B(t+1/t)=0$?

Continued:

> If $A$ and $B$ are not zero, we must have $-a-1=-b$ and $a-1=b$ in order to have the terms of biggest and smallest degree terms cancel, which is necessary for $\frac1t A(t+1/t)+B(t+1/t)=0$. But this means $a+1=b=a-1$, a contradiction. So one of $A$ or $B$ must be zero, which implies the other is zero, and you're done.

Comment: Can we conclude the same if $R$ is a ring,$0 \neq f \in R$,  $A(x), B(x) \in R[x]$ and $fA(f+\frac{1}{f})+B(f+\frac{1}{f})=0$ ?

Comment: You are using the fact that $1, t, t^2. \ldots, \frac{1}{t}, \frac{1}{t^2}, \ldots, $ is a $k$ basis right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the fact that $t^i$ forms a basis of $k[t,t^{-1}]$ as a $k$-module. That's still true when you change $k$ to some other ring. Your first question seems a bit iffy to me - first, you should assume $f$ is invertible, not just nonzero; next, we're relying on the fact that there aren't any interesting cancellations between powers of $f$ - you can easily cook up rings and $f$s where such things do happen. For instance, if you take $R=\Bbb C$ and pick an appropriate root of unity for $f$, you'll find a counterexample.